# Posting data in Tab based page by partialview

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I have 3 tabs in my Page and I used JQuery UI for tabs.

```
<div id="tabs" style="text-align:right;">
<ul>
    <li class="myTab">
    <a href="#tabs-1">Main Information</a></li>
    <li class="myTab"><a href=<%= Url.Action("GetPartialView","Contractors") %>                >Contractors</a></li>
    <li class="myTab"><a href="#tabs-3"> Consultants </a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">

</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
</div>
```

There is a "Save" button in each tab.The problem is that when for example button "Save" of contractors tab was clicked the page redirect  to http://localhost:1347/xxxxx/GetPartialView and didn't fire any method.I want to save data and show user a message that shows data was saved completely.How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the `[HttpPost]` attribute on top of whatever action is being called to load that page?